# Kernel Panics of SSD.

Tags: high-sierra

After force shut down I get continuous restarts with kernel panics. I’ve erased the disk and it restarts again when reinstalling macOS from Recovery Mode. Booting macOS/win from USB stick works fine. Apple Hardware Test and Diagnostic finds no errors. “diskutil zeroDisk force disk0” run from USB stick or Recovery Mode crashes at 10-11%.

I feel that there are bad blocks on SSD that kext doesn’t identify correctly but I can point manually.

macOS High Sierra 10.13.4. MacBook Pro 13” Late 2016, no TB

Thanks!

Comment: So, just to summarize, anytime you try to do something with the internal SSD, the system crashes?

Comment: Yes. But it crashes at 10-11% of macOS download, or 4% of "diskutil zeroDisk". So internal SSD works partially.

Comment: Then you have a hardware issue.  No software will fix this.  You need to take it in for service.

Comment: You might try accessing it via Target Disk Mode from another Mac. Alternatively, is this an SSD you can remove? If so I'd stick it in an external enclosure to work on it.

Comment: We are for the community not for $$z

Comment: @arcdale thats for a Target Mode advice (I didn't know about it and it's cool). I've erased SSD already and don't have other Mac...

Comment: Here is Kernel Panics report - https://pastebin.com/Y8zbVeLF